# How to update value in previous screen in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

i am navigating from one screen to another and passing data using *@Binding* but I am alo trying to update value back to first screen when its updating in second screen.

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @State private var valueToPass : Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.valueToPass += 1
            }) {
                Text("Increase value \(self.valueToPass)")
            }
        }
        .overlay(
            SecondView(valueToGet: $valueToPass)
        )
    }
}
      
struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var valueToGet: Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Show value \(valueToGet)")
                .padding(.top, 50)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change value in SecondView without dismissing overlay need updated value that in first view.

I am not sure how should i do same in reverse.

Comment: Binding as you did must be ok. Also remove navigation view from second view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close.

Just add a buttons in the second view to increment the value

```
struct SecondView: View {
    
    @Binding var valueToGet: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text("Show value \(valueToGet)")
            Button("Increment") {
                valueToGet += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you..but what if we dont have back button but SecondView is overlay on FirstView?

Comment: An `overlay` is part of the same view (`FirstView`). If you mean a sheet you can dismiss it by swiping down or add a button and `@Environment(\.dismiss)` and call `dismiss()`

Comment: I updated question, yes we can do that but if i dont want to dismiss overlay and still update the value..will this work?

Comment: Yes, a Binding is a Binding.